# lookupTransform and tf2_echo shows different results

Tags: ros, ros2, transforms, eigen, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am writing code for transformations using apriltag.

```
tf_buffer_->lookupTransform(tag_frame_, camera_frame_, tf2::TimePointZero);
```

gives different transformation matrix values compared to

```
ros2 run tf2_ros tf2_echo camera_frame_ tag_frame_
```

tf2_echo:

```
- Matrix:
  0.984  0.162 -0.068 -0.405
  0.123 -0.912 -0.391 -0.223
 -0.125  0.376 -0.918  0.937
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.962  0.256 -0.097 -0.311
  0.199 -0.896 -0.396 -0.186
 -0.189  0.362 -0.913  0.929
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.972  0.234 -0.024 -0.437
  0.215 -0.924 -0.316 -0.181
 -0.097  0.302 -0.948  0.988
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.957  0.289  0.033 -0.388
  0.278 -0.876 -0.393 -0.157
 -0.085  0.385 -0.919  0.986
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.943  0.325  0.074 -0.327
  0.332 -0.893 -0.305 -0.168
 -0.033  0.313 -0.949  1.008
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.952  0.299 -0.071 -0.174
  0.266 -0.918 -0.295 -0.229
 -0.153  0.262 -0.953  0.934
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.934  0.323 -0.149 -0.099
  0.264 -0.910 -0.320 -0.241
 -0.239  0.260 -0.935  0.931
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.911  0.301 -0.282  0.075
  0.234 -0.941 -0.246 -0.252
 -0.339  0.158 -0.928  0.982
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.904  0.310 -0.295  0.175
  0.253 -0.943 -0.215 -0.213
 -0.345  0.120 -0.931  0.991
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
- Matrix:
  0.853  0.311 -0.419  0.175
  0.240 -0.947 -0.213 -0.211
 -0.463  0.081 -0.883  0.865
  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.000
```

lookupTransform:

```
cam -> tag:
  0.993005   0.115175 -0.0259908   0.480949
  0.115586  -0.903337   0.413064  -0.542837
 0.0240963  -0.413179  -0.910331   0.743633
         0          0          0          1
cam -> tag:
    0.961699     0.198847    -0.188665     0.511308
    0.256293    -0.896393     0.361654    -0.422628
   -0.097204    -0.396155    -0.913024     0.743996
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
cam -> tag:
    0.961699     0.198847    -0.188665     0.511308
    0.256293    -0.896393     0.361654    -0.422628
   -0.097204    -0.396155    -0.913024     0.743996
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
cam -> tag:
    0.956792      0.27811   -0.0848747     0.498498
     0.28892    -0.876387      0.38532    -0.405495
   0.0327782    -0.393193    -0.918872     0.856553
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
cam -> tag:
    0.939404     0.342707  -0.00846977     0.407591
    0.326405    -0.886622     0.327659    -0.352925
    0.104781    -0.310569    -0.944758     0.968488
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
cam -> tag:
    0.951675     0.266108    -0.153299     0.369307
     0.29877    -0.917761     0.261632     -0.40231
   -0.071069     -0.29479    -0.952916     0.809793
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
cam -> tag:
    0.934415     0.263749    -0.239384     0.379393
    0.323434    -0.909803     0.260095    -0.429692
   -0.149192    -0.320462    -0.935439     0.778602
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
cam -> tag:
     0.91128     0.234292    -0.338638     0.323273
    0.300529    -0.940601      0.15796    -0.414841
   -0.281515    -0.245716    -0.927563     0.869551
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
cam -> tag:
    0.916233     0.259035    -0.305643     0.234101
    0.310183    -0.941478     0.131931    -0.384305
   -0.253581    -0.215685    -0.942962     0.939625
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
cam -> tag:
    0.853249     0.240313    -0.462834     0.301601
    0.310555    -0.947119    0.0807536     -0.32455
   -0.418953    -0.212638    -0.882759     0.791917
6.91763e-310 7.29112e-304            0            1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409243/lookuptransform-and-tf2_echo-shows-different-results/) by [MrOCW](https://answers.ros.org/users/95995/mrocw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2022-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-11-11**:
Shouldn't the last row be `[0, 0, 0, 1]` in the output of lookupTransform of the right side?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2022-11-11**:
Please copy and paste the console info into questions instead of screenshotting. It's not easily debugged without being able to copy and paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The echo command outputs the transform from the source frame to the target frame.

The lookupTransform API provides the transform to take data from the `source_frame` to the `target_frame`

There's been a lot of threads about it one of the original is here: https://github.com/ros/geometry/issues/108

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrOCW](https://answers.ros.org/users/95995/mrocw/) on 2022-11-11**:
OK got it so to get coordinate of B with reference to coordinate of A, i have to use: tf_buffer_->lookupTransform(A Frame, B Frame_, tf2::TimePointZero);